# Count objects that match criteria at a given time with paper_trail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I'm using [paper_trail gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) to track changes to 'status' attribute of my Book model.

I know I can easily get a status of a particular book at a given time with 'version_at'.

Can I count all the books that had a particular status at a given time with this gem?

**Update:** I found the solution to show all versions with a particular status, but still no luck with getting records with such status at a given time:

```
PaperTrail::Version.where(item_type: 'Book').where_object(status_id: 2).count
```

Comment: Just looking through the paper_trail readme - is there a created_at attribute on versions?

Comment: Yes, it is!!!  Will it help?

Comment: The problem is that I don't need all the versions that were created at some moment. I need all the versions that, for example, at June 1 00:00:00 had status 2.

Comment: Does paper_trail store the entire attributes hash for each version? Or just which attributes have changed, which would make it more difficult?

Comment: It saves the entire attributes hash for each version

Answer (score 0):

> Can I count all the books that had a particular status at a given time
>   with this gem?

```
::Book.
  versions.
  where_object(status_id: 2).
  between(start_time, end_time)
```

The `between` method is not documented, but it's OK to use it. I think it was intended to be part of the API. It can be found in `paper_trail/version_concern.rb`. If you want to submit a PR that documents it, that'd be great.